# Splitting work between multiple pollers?

Tags: zeromq, netmq, poller

My current setup for work on server side is like this -- I have a manager (with poller) which waits for incoming requests for work to do. Once something is received it creates worker (with separate poller, and separate ports/sockets) for the job, and further on worker communicates directly with client.

What I observe that when there is some intense traffic with any of the worker it disables manager somewhat -- `ReceiveReady` events are fired with significant delays.

[NetMQ documentation](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/poller/) states "Receiving messages with poller is slower than directly calling Receive method on the socket. When handling thousands of messages a second, or more, poller can be a bottleneck." I am so far below this limit (say 100 messages in a row) but I wonder whether having multiple pollers in single program does not clip performance even further.

I prefer having separate instances because the code is cleaner (separation of concerns), but maybe I am going against the principles of ZeroMQ? **The question is** -- is using multiple pollers in single program performance wise? Or in reverse -- do multiple pollers starve each other by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Professional system analysis may even require you to run multiple `Poller()` instances:

Design system based on facts and requirements, rather than to listen to some popularised opinions.

Implement performance benchmarks and measure details about actual implementation. Comparing facts against thresholds is a.k.a. a Fact-Based-Decision.

---

### If not hunting for the last few hundreds of [ns], a typical scenario may look this way:

your core logic inside an event-responding loop is to handle several classes of ZeroMQ integrated signallin / messaging inputs/outputs, all in a principally non-blocking mode plus your design has to spend specific amount of relative-attention to each such class.

One may accept some higher inter-process latencies for a remote-keyboard ( running a CLI-interface "across" a network, while your event-loop has to meet a strict requirement not to miss any "fresh" update from a QUOTE-stream. So one has to create a light-weight Real-Time-SCHEDULER logic, that will introduce one high-priority `Poller()` for non-blocking ( zero-wait ), another one with ~ 5 ms test on reading "slow"-channels and another one with a 15 ms test on reading the main data-flow pipe. If you have profiled your event-handling routines not to last more than 5 ms worst case, you still can handle TAT of 25 ms and your event-loop may handle systems with a requirement to have a stable control-loop cycle of 40 Hz.

Not using a set of several "specialised" pollers will not allow one to get this level of scheduling determinism with an easily expressed core-logic to integrate in such principally stable control-loops.

### Q.E.D.

<sub>I use similar design so as to drive heterogeneous distributed systems for FOREX trading, based on external AI/ML-predictors, where transaction times are kept under ~ 70 ms ( end-to-end TAT, from a QUOTE arrival to an AI/ML advised XTO order-instruction being submitted ) right due to a need to match the real-time constraints of the control-loop scheduling requirements.</sub>

---

### Epilogue:

If the documentation says something about a poller performance, in the ranges above 1 kHz signal delivery, but does not mention anything about a duration of a signal/message handling-process, it does a poor service for the public.
The first step to take is to measure the process latencies, next, analyse the performance envelopes. All ZeroMQ tools are designed to scale, so has the application infrastructure -- so forget about any SLOC-sized examples, the bottleneck is not the poller instance, but a poor application use of the available ZeroMQ components ( given a known performance envelope was taken into account ) -- one can always increase the overall processing capacity available, with ZeroMQ we are in a distributed-systems realm from a Day 0, aren't we?

So in concisely designed + monitored + adaptively scaled systems **no choking will appear**.

Comment: Can you define "TAT"?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. **TAT** stands for **T**urn **A**round **T**ime ( in a process / transaction end to end / E2E measurement / testing context )